# Does there always exist one plane onto which any two lines in $\Bbb{R}^3$ can be projected and intersect?

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, 3d

### Question

Consider the vectorial equations of any two lines in $\Bbb{R}^3$ where the parameter $\lambda$ varies across the entire real line:

$$\pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = {\bf r}(\lambda) = {\bf s} + \lambda{\bf t}$$
$$\pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = {\bf f}(\lambda) = {\bf g} + \lambda{\bf h}$$

Must there exist at least one plane of the form $$\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}={\bf P}(\lambda,\mu) = {\bf a} + \lambda{\bf b} + \mu{\bf c}$$ having a normal unit vector $${\bf n}={{\bf b}\times{\bf c} \over \left\lvert{\bf b}\right\rvert \left\lvert{\bf c}\right\rvert}$$

such that the projections of the lines onto the plane, given by $${\bf r}_\parallel(\lambda)={\bf r}(\lambda) - \bigl( {\bf r}(\lambda)\cdot{\bf n}\bigr){\bf n}$$ $${\bf f}_\parallel(\lambda)={\bf f}(\lambda) - \bigl( {\bf f}(\lambda)\cdot{\bf n}\bigr){\bf n}$$

intersect each other at at least one point? If so, how can I prove this?

---

### My thoughts

I have a feeling that the position vectors ${\bf s}, {\bf g}, {\bf a}$ are irrelevant and that only the direction vectors ${\bf t}, {\bf h}, {\bf b}, {\bf c}$ should matter.

Eventually the matter must amount to supposing some $(\gamma, \eta)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ and then examining the system of parametric equations implied by $$\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}={\bf P}(\gamma, \eta)={\bf r}_\parallel(\gamma)={\bf f}_\parallel(\gamma)$$ perhaps as an augmented matrix.

I feel like if I spent enough time on this, I could brute-force my way through things. However, my practice with vectors in this manner is limited, so there probably is some technique that would greatly facilitate the proof of which I am unaware.

Any tips or ideas?

By the way, I’m asking this question purely out of curiosity. My class has already moved past this unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is no, but it's a great question. The key thing to realize is that if you start with *parallel* lines, the projections onto any plane will either be degenerate (if the plane is perpendicular to the direction vector of the lines) or again parallel. But if you start with *skew* lines (lines that are neither parallel nor intersecting), you can check that they lie in a unique pair of parallel planes, and so certainly projecting onto one of those, say, you'll get intersecting lines. (Draw a picture!)

**EDIT**: After a reprimand from the OP (:)), I change my answer to YES. If you start with parallel lines, they determine a unique plane. If you project onto a plane perpendicular to it, but parallel to the original lines, you get a single line. Two lines that coincide entirely are, of course, technically intersecting.

**COMMENT**: By the way, you should check that if projecting on a plane $\Pi$ yields intersecting lines, for any *small* perturbation $\Pi'$ of $\Pi$, the same will be true. Of course, it's obvious that it's also always true for any $\Pi'$ parallel to $\Pi$, so only the normal vectors of the planes matter.

Comment: It is a nice question.  The case of rwo parallel lines is crucial, but we might view a projection causing them to coincide as "intersecting" (along the entire lengths of the projections).

Comment: What is a “small perturbation” of a plane?

Comment: I had in mind a small perturbation of its normal vector together with, perhaps, a small translation (which, as I pointed out, is irrelevant in your case). If you go far in mathematics, you'll learn that there's a space (called a manifold) that parametrizes $k$-dimensional linear (or affine) subspaces of a given $\Bbb R^n$; it's called a Grassmannian.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are not parallel, the cross product will give a normal to a family of parallel planes.  Choose one and project the original lines onto it.  They will intersect.